# Dynamically import component in React based on config entries

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, import, react-router

I have multiple apps as part of one React-redux-typescript project. All of these individual apps are part of a core-application. I want to dynamically set up routing.

My current routes look like this:

**Routes.tsx**

```
import HomePageApp  from "../Components/Home/HomeApp";
import TestApp from "../Components/Test/TestApp";
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
        <RedirectIfAuthenticated
        exact={true}
        isAuthenticated={true}
        path={Path.homePath} --> "/"
        component={HomePage} ---> AppName coming from import statement on top
        redirectPath={Path.homePath} -->  "/"
        />
        <RedirectIfAuthenticated
        isAuthenticated={true}
        path={Path.apps.test} --> "/test"
        component={TestApp} --> AppName from import on top
        redirectPath={Path.homePath} --> "/"
        />
     </Switch>
   );
}
```

And RedirectIfAuthenticated simply redirects to correct applications' landing pages.

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.tsx**

```
export default function RedirectIfAuthenticated({
    component,
    redirectPath,
    isAuthenticated,
    ...rest
}: IRedirectIfAuthenticatedProps) {
    const Component = component;
    const render = (renderProps: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
        let element = <Component {...renderProps} />;
        return element;
    };

    return <Route {...rest} render={render}/>;
}
```

I've a config file like this:

**Manifest.ts**

```
export let manifest = {
  apps: [
    {
      componentPath: "/Test/App",
      path: "/test",
      name: "Test"
    },
   ...more objects for other apps
  ]
};
```

In my Routes.tsx, I want to make use of my manifest to render the RedirectIfAuthenticated component.

so I can figure out this change:

*for brevity showing the dirty approach but the actual code iterates over the manifest using .map and renders RedirectIfAutenticated.*

```
const app = manifest.apps.find(app => app.name === "Test");
<Switch>
  <RedirectIfAuthenticated
  isAuthenticated={true}
  path={app.path} --> "/test"
  component={What should I do here? How to pass component reference by path??} 
  redirectPath={"/"} ==> I typically get this from my manifest..
  />
</Switch>
```

One option is to do this:

```
component={require("path from manifest").default}
```

but our tslint throws a bunch of errors at this. Other than this I can't figure out how to pass the component reference here dynamically. Looking for a better approach.

The Routes.tsx needs to be dynamic so that adding new apps is a matter of configuration so I can't do imports on top because I dont know what's gonna be added in config. Thanks.

Comment: If your React version is `v16.6.x` then you can try to use [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) doing something like `component={React.lazy(() => import("path from manifest"))}` <- you don't need to extract `.default` with `lazy` as it's done automatically.  Also refer to my *Shameless Plug*: [Loading React Components Dynamically on Demand](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2017/12/03/loading-react-components-dynamically-demand/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use dynamic imports to achieve this. I used [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2018/01/14/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions) article to understand a few concepts.

```
 private loadComponentFromPath(path: string) {
    import(`../../ScriptsApp/${path}`).then(component =>
      this.setState({
        component: component.default
      })
    );
  }
```

One important distinction here is if I don't give the path from the root of the app, I get an error saying "Unable to find the module". This is why I've given the full path from the root.